# File Explorer and icons look weird for seemingly no reason

Tags: nautilus, icons, 22.04

I'm on 22.04. I've noticed the icons didn't look normal at all, but most importantly, this is what Nautilus looks like:

[image]

I don't think this is normal! How can I make be the default again? And the icons look like this:

[image]

The question mark one is the Ubuntu Software thing.

The top bar button looks like

[image]

which is def not what it did before!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Head over to "Preferences" - "Accessibility. Turn the "High contrast" setting off.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in Nautilus is the icon set HiColor. Swith to Humanity to use the defaut icon set. Image using a dark theme and showing HiColor on Budgie (it is the same for Ubuntu with Nautilus):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I switched it to humanity and it didn't change a thing, even after rebooting...